# Invalid column name sql error when adding and updating at same time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to add and update column at same time, below is my query.I don't want to use NOT NULL DEFAULT constraint.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
TABLE_NAME = 'table1' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'new col')
BEGIN 
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD "new col" varchar(MAX)
EXEC ('UPDATE table1 SET "new col" = '''' ');
END
```

But its throwing me an error Invalid column name 'new col'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this doesn't look mysql to me. Why `EXEC` it runs in separate session

Comment: I'm not sure what the objection is to using `not null default`. *Removing* a default and *allowing* nulls are both trivial metadata-only operations which you could quickly perform after the initial `alter`.

Comment: I also wanted to drop that column later in future,but when I do that I also have to drop constraint, therefore I do not wanted to use "not null" constraint.

Answer (score 0):

if not exists(Select name from sys.columns where name = 'IncOHSRepEvent' and

object_id = object_id('Inc01_CA')) ALTER TABLE [Inc01_CA] ADD [IncOHSRepEvent]

varchar(200) NULL

Please try above with your values. Also in above query
Column name = IncOHSRepEvent'
Table Name = 'Inc01_CA'

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD [new col] varchar(MAX)
EXEC ('UPDATE table1 SET [new col] = '''' ');
```

We cannot use "Column" for table names and columns